# JSoup.connect throws 403 error while apache.httpclient is able to fetch the content

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML dump of any given page. I used [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) and also tried [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) for parsing.

I found useful functions in Jsoup but I am getting 403 error while calling `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

I tried HTTPClient, to get the html dump and it was successful for the same url.

Why is JSoup giving 403 for the same URL which is giving content from commons http client?
Am I doing something wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: please, shre the link. you connectiong to.

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508813/can-jsoup-simulate-a-button-press, reports of a similar problem

Comment: I'd try tcpdump or similar tool to see the differencies of what data are sent by HTTP Client and what by JSoup.

Comment: @vacuum https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=HTML+Parser+library

Comment: @AkashYadav Thanks! User Agent thing makes sense and works!

Comment: @instanceOfObject You should post your working solution as an answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Working solution is as follows (Thanks to  Angelo Neuschitzer for reminding to put it as a solution):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag(HTML.Tag.CITE.toString);
for (Element link : links) {
            String linkText = link.text();
            System.out.println(linkText);
}
```

So, **userAgent** does the trick :)