# 403 error while getting the google result using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get Google results using the following code:

```
Document doc = con.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=lakshman").timeout(5000).get();
```

But I get this exception:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403,URL=http://www.google.com/search?q=lakshman
```

A 403 error means the server is forbidding access, but I can load this URL in a web browser just fine.  Why does Jsoup get a 403 error?

Comment: It's probably the absence of a `USER_AGENT` header that triggers the 403. I think this is against Google's TOS in any case

Comment: oh.thanks for the warning.then is there a way to get the google result by automating?

Comment: I think they used to have a search API, but I'm not sure what the status is

Comment: You can set user-agent using jsoup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120849/jsoup-connect-throws-403-error-while-apache-httpclient-is-able-to-fetch-the-cont/10136686#10136686

Comment: @lakshman can u demonstrate your solution .I got this problem too.

Comment: @Vito: Solution is to add the user agent property as mentioned by Liang or use the search API.

Comment: .@lakshman I have added this`userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")` or modified to my own browser version .The 403 error still exists .

Comment: @Vito userAgent("Mozilla") worked and below 2 options didn't work //final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"; //final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36";

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You just need to add the UserAgent property to HTTP header as follows:

```
Jsoup.connect(itemUrl)
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
     .get()
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: userAgent("Mozilla") worked and below 2 options didn't work //final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36";
        //final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36";

Comment: Interestingly, in my case the user agent string in the answer didn't resolve the problem but my browser's actual user agent string, `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0`, did.

Comment: Not working in 2023, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227173/jsoup-connect-is-throwing-403-for-valid-login-credential-cookie-value

Answer (score 6):

Google doesn't allow robots, you couldn't use jsoup to connect google.
You can use the [Google Web Search API (Deprecated)](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can evade 403 error by just adding a user-agent

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(timeout)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
```

But that is against the google policy I think.

EDIT: Google catches robots quicker than you think. You can however, use this as a temporary solution.

Comment: Not working in 2023, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227173/jsoup-connect-is-throwing-403-for-valid-login-credential-cookie-value

Answer (score 1):

Replace statement

```
Document doc =con.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=lakshman").timeout(5000).get();
```

with statement

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=lakshman").userAgent("Chrome").get();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Document doc =con.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=lakshman").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(5000).get();
```

in case userAgent did not work Just like it didn't for me.

Comment: Not working in 2023, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227173/jsoup-connect-is-throwing-403-for-valid-login-credential-cookie-value

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you need to set a referrer. It helped in my case.

The full source [here](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-set-referrer-example/765)

```
    try{

        String strText = 
                Jsoup
                .connect("http://www.whatismyreferer.com")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .text();

        System.out.println(strText);

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ioe);
    }
```