# Jsoup POST: Defining a selected option to return HTML?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to generate a HTML post to a page which has a list of options. There is a drop down list where the user selects an item and then clicks a generate button. Depending on the option selected it returns various results. I did a comparison of the HTML before and after and can see the differences as follows:

Before

```
<option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
```

After

```
<option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Option2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
```

I can't figure out the syntax for the jsoup document generation. So far I have this but it just keeps returning the original HTML with no result:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("MYurl...")
.timeout(5000)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
.cookie("auth", "token")
.data("selected", "Option2")
.post();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use data to set a field's value **by its `name` attribute**.

When you use:

```
.data("selected", "Option2")
```

Is the same as having this element on the requesting page `form` (notice the `name="selected"`):

```
<select name="selected">
    <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

So, the way you are trying to `POST` is correct. The thing is probably the parameter (field) named `selected` does not exist in the `form` (that you are trying to emulate) and thus sending it is the same as sending nothing.

#### Edit after your comment:

> What I really need to do perform a click on the web page element before parsing and from what I understand this can't be done with Jsoup.

You are correct. Jsoup doesn't support that - a click can have several side-effects like JavaScript events and so on. Processing them is a big deal.

To your specific case, though, jsoup's capabilities of altering the DOM can be useful. Check the example below. In it we "select" an option by explicitly setting its `selected` attribute as `selected` (and remove it from every other option).

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class JSoupChangeDom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(""+
        " <html><body>                                            " +
        " <div>example</div>                                      " +
        " <form>                                                  " +
        "    <select name='mySelect'>                             " +
        "       <option value='Option1'>Option 1</option>         " +
        "       <option value='Option2'>Option 2</option>         " +
        "       <option value='Option3'>Option 3</option>         " +
        "    </select>                                            " +
        " <form>                                                  " +
        " </body></html>                                          ");
        Element mySelect = 
                      doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "mySelect").get(0);
        String optionValueToBeSelected = "Option2";
        Elements options = mySelect.getElementsByTag("option");
        for (Element option : options) {
            if (option.attr("value").equals(optionValueToBeSelected)) {
                option.attr("selected", "selected");
            } else {
                option.removeAttr("selected");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>example</div>
        <form>
            <select name="mySelect">
                <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="Option2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
                <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but I think I've approached this issue all wrong. I figured out that I could set the attribute using Jsoup but when I post the modified HTML back to the server it just returns the option as selected. What I really need to do perform a click on the web page element before parsing and from what I understand this [can't be done with Jsoup.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318991/perform-click-on-web-page-element-before-parsing-in-java)

Comment: Also because I'm trying to do this in Android it seems [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721544/httpunit-htmlunit-equivalent-for-android) is my best option but as is mentioned there it really is overkill for what I want to do.

Comment: You are correct. As an addition, I edited the answer. Check it out, it may be of help.