# Select link in HTML table using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How can I click on a link in an HTML table using Jsoup and load the document. 
I was able to obtain the href but it's not properly formatted so i can't load the page.

```
Element table = doc.select("table.dxgvTable_Office2010Blue");
Elements l = table.select("a");
for(Element links : l){
    System.out.println(links.text() + "\t" + links.attr("href"));
}
```

Below is the html code for every row in the table

```
</tr><tr id="ctl00_pageMain_dataGrid_DXDataRow8" class="dxgvDataRow_Office2010Blue">
                        <td class="dxgv"><a class="dxeHyperlink_Office2010Blue" href="javascript:focusedRowField.Set(&#39;row&#39;, dataGridClient.GetRowKey(dataGridClient.GetFocusedRowIndex())); drilldown_button.DoClick();">Canadian Short Term Fixed Income</a></td><td class="dxgv" align="right">47,591</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">4.21 %</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">260.2</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">0.55%</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">2,154.9</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">44,970</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">4.79%</td><td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
```

How do I click on the Link 'Canadian Short Term Fixed Income' if the output below is what is saved in href?

```
javascript:focusedRowField.Set('row',
    dataGridClient.GetRowKey(dataGridClient.GetFocusedRowIndex()));  
drilldown_button.DoClick();
```

How can i perform the click on the url using Java?

Comment: Post the html you are referring to.

Comment: I have modified my the question and have added the html.

Comment: You can't execute JavaScript with Jsoup, but it is possible to click on elements, see [Can Jsoup simulate a button press?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508813/can-jsoup-simulate-a-button-press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't click on a button with JSoup. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a parser to extract/manipulate the information but you can't trigger an action and have the associated javascript executed.

One easy way to achieve that would be to use a tool to automate a real browser, something like [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24744849/25122).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Selenium, it's such an amazing tool