# Programatically Trigger HTML Button in Java

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, kotlin, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape a HTML page with jsoup. However, in order to get the data I need I need to click an HTML button (`<button>` not `<input>`). Is there any way to do so in Java/Kotlin?

Here is the what the button HTML looks like:

`<button type="button" class="btn table-toggle" data-column="0,1,2,3,4" data-sort="1" data-sort-dir="desc">Base Stats</button>`

This is not the same as [Can Jsoup simulate a button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508813/can-jsoup-simulate-a-button-press) that question was talking about an `<input>` form, this is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Jsoup simulate a button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508813/can-jsoup-simulate-a-button-press)

Comment: You can invoke it with JS via Selenium: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: @CardinalSystem that one uses the `<input>` tag

Answer (score -1):

Try this in HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hover over the checkbox to simulate a mouse-click.</p>
  <button id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('click event occured')">Foo</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the question :/